# NodeJS + SocketIO android battery issue

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

I am using node.js socket.io library for building a android chat application with socket connection.
but socket connection consume too much power that it drain battery by very high rate.

so 
is it possible to minimize power consumption by any mean of keeping socket idle or anything

below is my code where i have added in IOConnection.java class

```
public void transportMessage(String text) {
    // my logic
}
```

Comment: Is there a lot of chatter on the socket (at a lower level)? How do you know it's the socket causing the battery drain specifically? Are you using Wifi or cell signal to communicate?

Comment: Thank-you for your reply. you are right about your doubt that socket is causing the battery drain specifically. 
plz see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lot of google and debuging i finally found solution and i hope it may help someone.

**Actual Problem:**

this problem is less concern to battery but more with Garbage collector which goes crazy after calling socket.disconnect() method.
it cause your app to slow down and drain battery quickly.

**Solution:**

use java-websocket.jar version 1.3.0 instead of websocket.jar to resolve this.

**More information:**

see this [issue](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client/issues/4) 
and read comment of  kikoso and lukas-hetzenecker

Comment: This lib Is for android?