# Decentralized Chat Communication Protocol

Tags: android, node.js, websocket, xmpp, chat

I am designing a chat application in which there is no central server or db handling all the incoming and outgoing messages. It will be entirely decentralized.

A sum up of my project and its requirements

- Each user will communicate via android phone to a particular `node` allotted to them. This node will then communicate directly with the `node` belonging to the user he wishes to message
- Chat messages will be communicated between `nodes` via a `p2p` protocol forked from one of the libraries used for `Ethereum`
- The chat will have a limited number of users, 1500-2500
- Mapping the nodes to the users will be done via DHT and is not an issue
- I want to depend as little as possible on GCM
- The server will be written entirely in Node js. I have read extensively on XMPP, socketio and websockets but am unable to come to a conclusion on what to use. Keeping in mind that the code I write will be deployed across multiple `nodes` i.e. servers
- And of course, the app will have a background service running and will need to show notifications for new messages when the app is in the back ground or not running at all
- A quick deployment is the least important factor for me. I am just looking for the most powerful and customizable end product
- I would like to stick with nodejs for the server

Is the primary advantage of XMPP over websockets that in XMPP a lot of the features needed for chat is out-of-the-box? Or is there more to it?

I have a list of libraries obtained from various stack questions and seen examples for xmpp and websocket implementations.

An increase in delay of a 1-2 seconds is NOT a problem in my case, but battery conversation is important.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033390/nodejs-socketio-android-battery-issue) suggests battery consumption with websockets is not a problem.

Comment: `advantage of XMPP over websockets`. You are comparing a protocol with a socket technique. I do not understand that.

Comment: `the app will have a backround server running`. A server or a client?

Comment: Meant was the combination of node and socket vs implementation of xmpp

Comment: Sorry,  autocorrect,  app will have a service running,  like a broadcast receive so it can get messages even if the app is not running

Answer (score -1):

Check [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/) protocol. It's lightweight and uses minimum data.